# CIColorMatrix math doesn't make sense

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

I'm trying to use CIColorMatrix in Swift on iOS, and I'm coming up with a result that doesn't match my understanding of how it is supposed to work.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorMatrix) defines it as:

```
s.r = dot(s, redVector)
s.g = dot(s, greenVector)
s.b = dot(s, blueVector)
s.a = dot(s, alphaVector)
s = s + bias
```

So let's say I have an input pixel with the RGBA values [255, 0, 0, 255] (100% red). And I apply the vector [0.5, 0, 0, 0] to the red channel. Shouldn't this result in a red channel value of **127**?

```
(255*0.5)+(0*0)+(0*0)+(255*0) = 127.5
```

For some reason, with these values, CIColorMatrix is giving me a value of **187**. Is this not the definition of dot() that they are talking about?

Here's a code snippet (the input image is all red).

```
// Before this, the RGB values are [255, 0, 0]
let vec = CIVector(x: 0.5, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0)
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix")
filter!.setDefaults()
// Default bias is [0,0,0,0] (explicitly setting it as such doesn't change the result).
filter!.setValue(myImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter!.setValue(vec, forKey: "inputRVector")
// After this, the RGB values are [187, 0, 0]
```

What am I missing or misunderstanding here?

Comment: I realized after I posted this, that maybe something is messing with the values after the CIColorMatrix filter runs. I'm converting the CIImage to a CGImage with CIContext's createCGImage(), and that's where I'm sampling the pixel values. Is there some kind of tone mapping or gamma curve that gets applied in that step? I can't find anything about that in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Core Image filters operate in the working color space of the `CIContext` executing them. Filter kernels also work with alpha-unpremultiplied pixel values, while filter output is premultiplied. If you're seeing results that aren't what you expect, check that your working and output color spaces are configured as you want them, and make sure you aren't doing anything funny with alpha premultiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Another caveat on the CIColorMatrix filter is that its parameters are applied un un-premultiplied color values.  So in reality the kernel behaves as if its code looks like:

```
s = unpremultiply(s)
s.r = dot(s, redVector)
s.g = dot(s, greenVector)
s.b = dot(s, blueVector)
s.a = dot(s, alphaVector)
s = s + bias
s = premultiply(s)
```

If your colors are opaque (as with your example of [255, 0, 0, 255]) then the unpremultiply/premultiply have no effect.